# Excel Formatting Cell Conditions

Tags: excel

I have some large tables of data for percentages of employees in different areas with degrees for each month for the past year, I want to add a conditional format that highlights a cell green if the number increased from the previous month and red if it decreased. I know how to do this individually but I was wondering if there was a larger scale method to do this?

Comment: If you want someone to help you write a formula you will need to identify where all the data is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following assumes that the data is formatted such that the percentages of employees are all in the same row and the successive months are in consecutive columns.

Here's how I have my sheet set up:

[image]

What you can do to acquire the red/green formatting is highlight C2:M2, click Conditional Formatting under the Home ribbon, then select New Rule.  Next, click "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" and in the formula bar write the following:

```
=IF(C2 > B2, 1, 0)
```

Now click Format and go to the Fill tab.  Select any shade of green that you want and press OK.  Press OK once again on the Rule window and that "greater than" rule will be created.  Do the same thing but instead enter this formula

```
=IF(C2 < B2, 1, 0)
```

and select a shade of red and you should be good to go.

Comment: This does work bu t I have multiple rows of data. DO I have to do this one row at a time?

Comment: Nope.  You can just highlight all of the rows (starting in column C, that is) and apply the same formulas and it will work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility you did not mention is that cells that have not changed in value from one month to the next should be neither red nor green. That is still possible with just two rules if coupled with a default fill set as ‘standard’ fill rather than with conditional formatting, say red:

Select the range to be formatted, say C2:M100, and apply a ‘standard' fill of red colour. B2 is assumed to be a datapoint but since without precedent is not to be formatted.

Overwrite this with a conditional formatting rule using a formula to determine which cells to format such as:

```
=C2>B2
```

and select green fill.

Add a second rule of:

```
=C2=B2
```

and select white fill.

Since the rules are mutually exclusive, might as well check `Stop If True` for both.

There is no need for `=IF(…,1,0)` since this is *Conditional* Formatting and the IF is implied.

If you wanted say a traffic light analogy, with amber for ‘no change’, use a ‘standard’ amber fill for B2:M100, select C2 and apply:

```
=C2>B2
```

as above and select green fill but change the second rule to:

```
=C2<B2
```

and select red fill.

Ensure that the `Applies to` range for both the above is `=$C$2:$M$100` (this just being an alternative to starting by selecting `C2` rather than the entire applicable range).